# What is variable can be final in Netbeans mean?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been trying to create a code that will compute the windchill when a user inputs specific data. I am new to Java and have been having a lot of difficulty with this project. However, I finally got it to run successfully. Even though it is running now I keep getting messages saying that my variables could be made final. I am not sure what this means and cannot get it to go away. I marked the ones that had the message on them in a comment. Could someone please explain what this means and why its happening?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line;
        String date;
        int windSpeed, temperature;

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the observation date: ");
        date = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println ("Enter the wind speed in MPH: ");        
        line = kb.nextLine();
        windSpeed = Integer.parseInt(line);

        System.out.println ("Enter the temperature in degrees F: ");
        line = kb.nextLine();
        temperature = Integer.parseInt(line);

        Observation observation1 = new Observation(date,windSpeed,temperature);
        System.out.println("Observation Date: " + observation1.getDate());
        System.out.println("WindChill: " + observation1.getwindChill());

    }    
}
```

My other class in the same package:

```
public class Observation {
    private String date; //can be final
    private int windSpeed;//can be final
    private int temperature;//can be final
    private double windChill;//can be final      

    public Observation (String d, int s, int t){
        date = d;
        windSpeed = s;
        temperature = t;

        windChill = 35.74 + 0.6215*t + (0.4275*t - 35.75) * Math.pow(s,0.16);

    }

    public String getDate (){
        return date;
    }

    public double getwindChill(){
        return windChill;
    }
}
```

Comment: You set them in the constructor and only there.  This mean they do not change later, and behaves like final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final variables in Java are costants, this means that once you set their value, it never changes. NetBeans will suggest you to put a `final` modifier in the declaration of your variables when:

- you assign a value right after creation
- you initialize them in the constructor

and you never change their values.